# Cannot use Angular element in a separate html file

Tags: angular6

I have created an angular element inside an existing project using

```
let el = createCustomElement(BuildcardOnChatComponent, {injector});
customElements.define('my-buildcard-on-chat', el);
```

in app.module.ts and build it. Now when I am using my-buildcard-on-chat as a tag in a separate html file, the element is not rendering on browser. I have loaded the script created after building the project as per angular element docs.